# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Does any know why I am getting this error when trying to edit something in the database through the ForestLogisticBEAN class?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Here is the integration layer:

```
public void EditParcelDetail(ForestLogisticBEAN parcel){

    IQueryable<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;

    _ForestLogisticsBeans = (from order in _context.Orders
              from tracking in _context.Trackings
              where order.CustomerID == parcel.Id
              where tracking.CustomerId == parcel.Id
              select new {order.DeliveryDate, order.OrderDate, tracking.Status} ).ToList();
      }
```

Here is the ForestLogisticBEAN class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ForestLogistic.Data.BEANS
{
    public class ForestLogisticBEAN
    {

        public int TrackingId { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }

        public ForestLogisticBEAN() { }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I changed it to List instead of IQueryable but now it is throwing this error instead

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ForestLogistics.Data.BEANS.ForestLogisticBEAN]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'ForestLogistics.Data.Order'.

Here is the new integration layer:

```
public void EditParcelDetail(ForestLogisticBEAN parcel)

        {

                List<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;

              _ForestLogisticsBeans = (from order in _context.Orders
                                from tracking in _context.Trackings

                                 where order.CustomerID == parcel.Id
                                where tracking.CustomerId == parcel.Id
                                select new ForestLogisticBEAN {
                                    DeliveryDate = parcel.DeliveryDate,
                                    OrderDate = parcel.OrderDate,
                                    Status = parcel.Status

                                });

              _context.SaveChanges();

          }
```

The aim is to be able to combine the order and the tracking table with the bean class

Comment: Why do you declare it as `IQueryable<T>` instead of `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: Why not use var? `var _ForestLogisticsBeans = (from order in _context.Orders....`

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable.ToList` returns a `List<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IQueryable<T>`. So you cannot assign it to the `IQueryable<ForestLogisticBEAN>` variable.

So why don't you declare it as list or IEnumerable?

```
IEnumerable<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;
```

You also have to create instances of `ForestLogisticBEAN` instead of the anyonymous type that you're selecting. For example:

```
_ForestLogisticsBeans = (from order in _context.Orders
                         from tracking in _context.Trackings
                         where order.CustomerID == parcel.Id
                         where tracking.CustomerId == parcel.Id
                         select new ForestLogisticBEAN { 
                             Status  = tracking.Status,
                             OrderDate = order.OrderDate,
                             DeliveryDate = order.DeliveryDate
                         }).ToList();
```

Comment: I updated it with your recommendations but now I'm getting another error 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ForestLogistics.Data.BEANS.ForestLogisticBEAN]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ForestLogistics.Data.Order'.'

Comment: @RonS: i'm not familiar with MVC. But it seems that you use the wrong type for your model. So instead of `BEANS.ForestLogisticBEAN‌` use `Data.Order`.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear.

Define:

```
IEnumerable<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;
```

or

```
List<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you define `_ForestLogisticsBeans` as `IQueryable<ForestLogisticBEAN>`? You have defined it as `IQueryable` and you are assigning `List` It always give you error.

try `var _ForestLogisticsBeans = (from order in _context.Orders....`

Or use

```
IEnumerable<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;
```

Or

```
List<ForestLogisticBEAN> _ForestLogisticsBeans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Project in C# and Angular 2+ 
I am sure this would give result and this could be helpful to others while returning value i get

'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

my code is:

```
        List<Ticket> objTicket = new List<Ticket>();
        objTicket = ticketRepository.GetAllData().ToList();

        List<AccountType> ListAccounType = new List<AccountType>();
        ListAccounType = accountTypeRepository.GetAllData().ToList();

        List<AccountTransaction> ListAccount = new List<AccountTransaction>();
        ListAccount = accountTranastionRepository.GetAllData().ToList();

        List<AccountTransactionValue> ListAccountTransactionValue = new List<AccountTransactionValue>();
        ListAccountTransactionValue = accountTransactionValueRepository.GetAllData().ToList().Where(o => o.Date >= FromDate && o.Date <= ToDate).ToList();

        var ListAccountTransaction = from v in ListAccountTransactionValue
                                     join atr in objTicket on v.AccountTransactionId equals atr.Id
                                     join a in ListAccount on v.AccountId equals a.Id
                                     select new { v.Id, Name = a.Name, v.AccountTransactionId, VoucherNo = atr.Name.Substring(atr.Name.IndexOf("[")), AccountTransactionType = atr.Name.Substring(0, atr.Name.IndexOf("[")), atr.Date, SourceAccountTypeId = atr.Name, Description = atr.CompanyCode, DebitAmount = v.Debit, CreditAmount = v.Credit, atr.DepartmentId };

        var ListScreenTicketType = ListAccountTransaction.Select(o => new { o.Id }).Distinct().ToList();

        AccountTransactionDocument objAccountTransactionDocument = new AccountTransactionDocument();
        if (objAccountTransactionDocument != null)
        {
            AccountTransactionType objAccountTransactionType = new AccountTransactionType();
        }

        List<ScreenTicket> listScreenTicket = new List<ScreenTicket>();
        foreach (var accounttransaction in ListScreenTicketType)
        {
            var objaccounttransaction = ListAccountTransaction.Where(o => o.Id == accounttransaction.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            ScreenTicket objScreenTicket = new ScreenTicket();
            objScreenTicket.Id = accounttransaction.Id;
            objScreenTicket.Name = objaccounttransaction.Date.ToShortDateString();
            objScreenTicket.Note = objaccounttransaction.Name;
            var dataBytes = objaccounttransaction.Name;
            if (dataBytes != null)
            {
                objScreenTicket.IsActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                objScreenTicket.IsActive = false;
            }
            var objscreens = ListAccountTransaction.Where(o => o.Name == objaccounttransaction.Name);
            List<PaymentHistory> listPaymentHistory = new List<PaymentHistory>();
            foreach (var screenvalue in objscreens)
            {
                PaymentHistory objPaymentHistory = new PaymentHistory();
                objPaymentHistory.Id = screenvalue.Id;
                objPaymentHistory.AmountPaid = screenvalue.CreditAmount;
                objPaymentHistory.Id = screenvalue.Id;
                listPaymentHistory.Add(objPaymentHistory);
            }
            objScreenTicket.PaymentHistory = listPaymentHistory;
            listScreenTicket.Add(objScreenTicket);
        }
        return listScreenTicket;
    }
```